# ActiveRecord Relationships : undefined method for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Consider the following:

```
class Manager < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
end
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manager
end


employee = Employee.first
puts employee.manager.name
```

If for some reason an employee does not have a manager I get this:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Which makes sense. However, is there a clean/suggested way to handle this, so I don't always have to check and see if an employee actually has a manager before I ask for the manager's name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
puts employee.manager.name unless employee.manager.nil?
```

Or:

```
puts (employee.manager.nil? ? "No manager" : employee.manager.name)
```

Which is equivalent in this case to:

```
puts (employee.manager ? employee.manager.name : "No manager")
```

(Equivalent as long as employee.manager can't return false.)

Comment: I think that if there is no manager, that will print "nil", which is probably not desired.  I haven't tried it, though.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to be too clever. If you're going to use this repeatedly, make it a function.

```
class Employee
   def manager_name
     manager.try(:name).to_s # force empty string for nil        
   end
end
```

Comment: We used to do this, then realized our models were getting quite cluttered with lots and lots of methods.  Now we throw this kind of method into a `Decorator` via the draper gem: https://github.com/drapergem/draper -- But I do agree, it belongs in a method of some kind.

Comment: There are plenty of patterns for handling models with lots of methods. Another option would be to write your own version of rails' `delegate` that ignores nil things.

Comment: @nzifnab that gem looks pretty neat.

Answer (score 0):

You can check using the [`has_attribute?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/has_attribute%3F) method:

```
employee.has_attribute? :manager
```

So something like:

```
puts employee.manager.name if employee.has_attribute? :manager
```

Comment: No, you can't.  The `#has_attribute?` method returns whether the receiver's `attributes` hash contains the specified key.  So, first of all, `employee.has_attribute?(:manager) will always return false, because employee `belongs_to` manager; you would have to call `employee.has_attribute?(:manager_id) to get a meaningful response.  Second, `employee.has_attribute?(:manager_id)` will always return true, because all instances of the class have that attribute; it doesn't tell you anything about whether that attribute has a non-nil value.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to prefer `puts employee.manager.try(:name)`

The try method returns `nil` if it was called on `nil`, but will execute the method properly if `manager` wasn't nil.

If you want default text:

```
puts employee.manager.try(:name) || "No Manager"
```